# Laravel 5.5 Ajax Logout no redirect

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.5, logout

I'm trying to make a logout button inside a blade view which could logout user without redirecting them. I just want to reload the same page.

I thought ajax would be the the best way to do that, (but I may be wrong).

**Here is my button :**

```
@if (auth()->check())
  <p>Vous êtes identifié en tant que <strong>{{ auth()->user()->name }}</strong>. <a href="#" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">Se déconnecter ?</a>
     <form id="logout-form" action="{{ url('/logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
         {{ csrf_field() }}
     </form>
   </p>
@endif
```

**Here is my ajax function :**

```
<script>
// Ajax Logout
$('#logout-form').on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault(e);
    var dest_url = "{{ url('/logout') }}";
  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:dest_url,
    data:$(this).serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
    success: function(data){
      c = "success";
      t = "Succès";
      m = "Vous avez été déconnecté";
      i = "icon-circle-check";
      iziToast.show({
        class:"iziToast-"+c||"",
        title:t||"Sans titre",
        message:m||"-",
        animateInside:!1,
        position:"topRight",
        progressBar:!1,
        icon:i,
        timeout:9000,
        transitionIn:"fadeInLeft",
        transitionOut:"fadeOut",
        transitionInMobile:"fadeIn",
        transitionOutMobile:"fadeOut"
      });
    }
  })
});
</script>
```

**My route file (web.php)**

```
Auth::routes();
Route::post('logout', '\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout');
```

**LoginController.php**

```
 /**
 * Custom logout function with redirect back if ajax.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function logout(Request $request) {
    $this->guard()->logout();
    $request->session()->invalidate();
    $request->session()->flash('errors', 'Vous êtes déconnecté');
    if($request->ajax()) {
        return Response::json(array(
            'success' => true,
            'data'   => 'Vous êtes déconnecté'
        )); 
    }
    else {
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

I think I'm missing something...

Comment: What is your `dd($request->ajax())`?

Comment: I think you can use `return redirect()->back();` inside `return redirect('/');` for back to  previous page after `log out` (Without using Ajax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My request was not executed by Ajax, so I removed the `logout-form` form and I listened to the click event on the link.

I also had a syntax error in my ajax function, a ',' was missing before the 'error:' part.

Here is my full code working, and without superficious lines:

### Logout button

```
@if (auth()->check())
    <p>Vous êtes identifié en tant que <strong>{{ auth()->user()->name }} </strong>. <a id="logout_btn" href="#">Se déconnecter ?</a>
    </p>
@endif
```

### Ajax function

```
<script>
// Ajax Logout
    $('#logout_btn').click(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        var dest_url = "{{ url('/logout') }}";
  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:dest_url,
    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
    success: function(){
      c = "success";
      t = "Succès";
      m = "Vous avez été déconnecté";
      i = "icon-circle-check";
      iziToast.show({
        class:"iziToast-"+c||"",
        title:t||"Sans titre",
        message:m||"-",
        animateInside:!1,
        position:"topRight",
        progressBar:!1,
        icon:i,
        timeout:9000,
        transitionIn:"fadeInLeft",
        transitionOut:"fadeOut",
        transitionInMobile:"fadeIn",
        transitionOutMobile:"fadeOut"
      });
      $('form[name="reservation"]').load(document.URL +  ' form[name="reservation"]');
      $('.toolbar .account').load(document.URL +  ' .toolbar .account');

    },
    error: function(){
      console.log('Erreur lors de la déconnection via Ajax');

      c = "danger";
      t = "Erreur";
      m = "Une erreur s'est produite lors de la déconnection";
      i = "icon-ban";
      iziToast.show({
        class:"iziToast-"+c||"",
        title:t||"Sans titre",
        message:m||"-",
        animateInside:!1,
        position:"topRight",
        progressBar:!1,
        icon:i,
        timeout:9000,
        transitionIn:"fadeInLeft",
        transitionOut:"fadeOut",
        transitionInMobile:"fadeIn",
        transitionOutMobile:"fadeOut"
      });
    }
  })
});
</script>
```

### LoginController

```
/**
 * Custom logout function with no redirect if ajax.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function logout(Request $request) {
    $this->guard()->logout();
    $request->session()->invalidate();
    if($request->ajax()) {
        return Response::json(array(
            'success' => true,
            'data'   => 'Vous êtes déconnecté'
        )); 
    }
    else {
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```